# How to repeat a query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to repeat this query 100 times. I think I should use loop function but didn't find any solutions on how to do it.

```
select case when DBMS_RANDOM.value >= 0 and DBMS_RANDOM.value<=0.053 then 1
            when DBMS_RANDOM.value > 0.053 and DBMS_RANDOM.value <= 0.097 then 2
            when DBMS_RANDOM.value > 0.097 and DBMS_RANDOM.value <= 0.142 then 3
end random_groups
from temp_trt;
```

here is the sample data of temp_trt
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrwND.png)

Comment: Information on Oracle PL/SQL Loops: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/index.php

Comment: What are you going to do with the result of the query? How do you want it presented? How many rows in `temp_trt`?

Comment: You still haven't explained how you apply the contents of TMP_TRT in your process. The pasted image has five rows. Does that mean you want one result set of 5000 randomly generated values of `random_group`? If it had six rows would it be 6000? Do you use the contents in anyway other than to control the number of rows in the final result set? How do you populate TMP_TRT?

Comment: Also, please avoid the use of images for presenting code or data. Many people are unable to view images from image dump sites. Also, images cannot be used in test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call of `DBMS_RANDOM.value()` returns *a different value*. Consequently there is **no guarantee** that any call will fall between any of your bounds. In fact it's statistically unlikely. Consequently most of the time you'll get a NULL returned, because you have defined no ELSE branch.

Here is an alternate solution which generates one hundred random values.

```
with dr as (
    select DBMS_RANDOM.value val
    from dual
    connect by level <= 100 
)
select dr.val
      , case when dr.val >= 0 and dr.val<=0.053 then 1
            when dr.val > 0.053 and dr.val <= 0.097 then 2
            when dr.val > 0.097 and dr.val <= 0.142 then 3
            else 4 
end random_groups
from dr
;
```

Given the way your code defines the bounds of the branches, most of the `random_groups` will be `4`.

---

It's not clear from your posted (toy?) code what the role of TEMP_TRT is, so I decided to ignore it. Please **edit your question** to add more detail if this makes you unhappy

Comment: i want to get random number from table temp_trt. not dual

Comment: Fine. As I explained in my answer, I didn't understand how you were using TMP_TRT. Please **edit your question** to provide some sample data for TMP_TRT and demonstrate how that affects your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row generation tecnique by `select level ... connect by level >= 100` structure as

```
select level, rg.random_groups
 from
    ( select case when DBMS_RANDOM.value >= 0 and DBMS_RANDOM.value<=0.053 then 1
                when DBMS_RANDOM.value > 0.053 and DBMS_RANDOM.value <= 0.097 then 2
                when DBMS_RANDOM.value > 0.097 and DBMS_RANDOM.value <= 0.142 then 3
     end random_groups
    from dual ) rg
connect by level <= 100
```

Comment: I have withdrawn my PL/SQL solution, as it is clearly inferior to using a CONNECT BY in this case.