# Is this possible to repeat this code N times?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table ABC that has 10M+ rows. It contains customer_id, email, score. I created a query that randomly select 1,000 numbers and count them by groups. The output for this query is below.

```
RANDOM_GROUP    FREQ
1            71
2            45
3            35
4            45
5            53
6            40
7            65
8            54
9            68
10           59
11           465
```

This is my query:

```
select random_group, count(random_group) as freq
from
      (select case when rand_num >= 0 and rand_num<=0.053 then 1
                  when rand_num > 0.053 and rand_num <= 0.097 then 2
                  when rand_num > 0.097 and rand_num <= 0.142 then 3
                  when rand_num > 0.142 and rand_num <= 0.189 then 4
                  when rand_num > 0.189 and rand_num <= 0.234 then 5
                  when rand_num > 0.234 and rand_num <= 0.281 then 6
                  when rand_num > 0.281 and rand_num <= 0.341 then 7
                  when rand_num > 0.341 and rand_num <= 0.399 then 8
                  when rand_num > 0.399 and rand_num <= 0.458 then 9
                  when rand_num > 0.458 and rand_num <= 0.515 then 10
                  when rand_num > 0.515 and rand_num <= 1.000 then 11 end 
                  random_group
      from
            (SELECT dbms_random.value(0,1) AS rand_num, 
                    rownum as at_row_num
             FROM ABC                   
             WHERE rownum <= 1000))
group by random_group
order by random_group
;
```

Is this possible to repeat this query N times so that each output will generate different number counts? Shall I use a loop? I don't want to manually run N times to get different results...Thank you!

Comment: [This seems like a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55267096/146325).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query -this is your query but slightly modified for test urposes (it does not use ABC table and generates only 10 rows using `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10` clause - but you can replace 10 with 1000)

```
WITH My_Query As (
        select random_group, count(random_group) as freq
        from
              (select case when rand_num >= 0 and rand_num<=0.053 then 1
                          when rand_num > 0.053 and rand_num <= 0.097 then 2
                          when rand_num > 0.097 and rand_num <= 0.142 then 3
                          when rand_num > 0.142 and rand_num <= 0.189 then 4
                          when rand_num > 0.189 and rand_num <= 0.234 then 5
                          when rand_num > 0.234 and rand_num <= 0.281 then 6
                          when rand_num > 0.281 and rand_num <= 0.341 then 7
                          when rand_num > 0.341 and rand_num <= 0.399 then 8
                          when rand_num > 0.399 and rand_num <= 0.458 then 9
                          when rand_num > 0.458 and rand_num <= 0.515 then 10
                          when rand_num > 0.515 and rand_num <= 1.000 then 11 end 
                          random_group
              from
                    (SELECT dbms_random.value(0,1) AS rand_num, 
                            rownum as at_row_num
                     FROM dual
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10))
        group by random_group
        order by random_group
)
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT level as test_number FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100
) row_generator,
LATERAL (
    SELECT * FROM My_Query WHERE row_generator.test_number = row_generator.test_number
) x
;
```

BTW: this clause `WHERE row_generator.test_number = row_generator.test_number` seems to be redundant, but without this you will get wrong results - the same records repeated 100 times instead of random data for each test.

Comment: Thanks! but are we able to generate random number from this ABC table? I will need to compare the output with other outputs from other tables.